# Python Image Processing Library - Image Resizing in Linux

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image as image
img = image.open(filename)
img = img.resize((640,640))
```

This code works perfectly fine in windows but it is giving some problem in ubuntu.
The error is 
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/home/prathprabhudesai/Imagga/Classifiertraining.py", line 82, in <module>
    img = img.resize((640,640))                           #Resize 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1318, in resize
    self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 192, in load
    d = Image._getdecoder(self.mode, d, a, self.decoderconfig)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_getdecoder'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a similar problem because I was using Spyder. Check this thread: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.scientific.spyder/2465

Comment: Put some code as well besides link, if the link points to a solution. Otherwise remove it.